# fdisk says the partition I'm trying to recover is "unknown" type. Is there anyway to mount this?

Tags: data-recovery, fdisk, fsck, hfs+

I have a corrupt HFS partition that I'm trying to recover data from.

```
>>sudo fdisk -l
Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1         40    409639    409600   200M EFI System
/dev/sda2     409640 851522247 851112608 405.9G unknown
/dev/sda3  851522248 852791783   1269536 619.9M Apple HFS/HFS+
/dev/sda4  852791784 862557408   9765625   4.7G Linux swap
/dev/sda5  862558208 975839231 113281024    54G Linux filesystem
```

/dev/sda2 is the corrupt HFS partition I'm trying to recover.

fsck.hfsplus doesn't give me anything

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck.hfsplus -d /dev/sda2
** /dev/sda2
    Using cacheBlockSize=32K cacheTotalBlock=1024 cacheSize=32768K.
    Block 2 is not an MDB or Volume Header 
    Block 851112606 is not an MDB or Volume Header 
    unknown volume type 
    primary MDB is at block 0 0x00 
    alternate MDB is at block 0 0x00 
    primary VHB is at block 0 0x00 
    alternate VHB is at block 0 0x00 
    sector size = 512 0x200 
    VolumeObject flags = 0x01 
    total sectors for volume = 851112608 0x32baf2a0 
    total sectors for embedded volume = 0 0x00
```

`testdisk` doesn't even find this partition.

Is there anything else I can do to repair this partition? Or is this partition completely broken?

Comment: setting the partition type may make it visible to some tools.

Comment: Well this doesn't look good...


ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/sda2
Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x1ea73521.

Command (m for help): t
No partition is defined yet!

Comment: Do not do that.

Comment: Do what? I just tried to manually set the type with fdisk and it told me there was no partition on /dev/sda2. I didn't commit any changes.

Comment: That is not how you do it. The partition table is not in `sda2`, it is in `sda`. The partitions table is in the first few blocks, the partitions follow. So you need to specify `/dev/sda`. Be careful not to remove or adjust the other partitions. (and it did not tell you that there is no partition in `/dev/sda2`, it told you that there is no partition table in it.)

Comment: Ah okay. `sudo fdisk l` now tells me `/dev/sda2` is Apple HFS/HFS+, but `fsck.hfs` still gives me the same output. `testdisk` tells me `/dev/sda` is a "Bad MAC partition, invalid block0 signature \ read_part_mac: bad DPME signature"